# Removing AD Group Membership (PowerShell)

Tags: windows, powershell, active-directory, automation, server

I have a script for people who leave my organization.  It basically creates a user backup folder and file before changing the password, removing the manager, backing up all member of groups, removing all group memberships, disabling the account and moving to different OU.

The part that i seem to be stuck on is the membership removals. This is what i have for that task:

```
Get-ADPrincipalGroupMembership -Identity "$Username" | % {Remove-ADPrincipalGroupMembership -Identity "$Username" -MemberOf $_}
```

This DOES work but I am prompted to confirm Yes or No to each group. When i add:

```
-confirm $false
```

at the end, none of the groups are removed.  How can I get it to not ask for confirmation while still removing the groups?

Thank You!

Comment: It should be: `-Confirm:$false`

Comment: That actually still prompted for confirmation of all groups. Any other suggestion?

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me:

```
Get-ADPrincipalGroupMembership -Identity "$Username" | % {Remove-ADPrincipalGroupMembership -Identity "$Username" -MemberOf $_ -Confirm:$False}
```

No prompts and all of the removals worked just fine.

I wonder if there is a way to suppress the error message thrown up with respect to the user's Primary Group -- DomainMembers, in our case. I'm perfectly happy with the result (the command won't remove the user from his primary group, while the user is removed from all others), but the error message just *looks* ugly.`